# Giving birth twice in a month

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, pregnancy-birth

I came across an article about a woman with two wombs giving birth twice, nearly a month apart. How should such a woman deal with all the regular rules after giving birth.

Comment: How is this different from regular twins? I don't understand what you are unsure about.

Comment: @DoubleAA Basically since they are born a month apart rather than together as regular twins, would she start counting again. Since they would start nidah at different times, she would probably have to restart the count when either womb emits blood.

Comment: @sabba twins are born on different days about 1% of the time. How is this different

Comment: @DoubleAA ‘unsure’ isn’t the case here, I reformulated my question. All I wanted to know is how to deal with all the rules, because this seems to be a unique situation.

Comment: Lots of cases are unique (an 11.3 foot tall sukkah with 3.7 pink walls with blue stripes with red dots is certainly unique) but fewer are confusing. Is there one of the regular rules which you are unsure how to apply?

Comment: 1. She does not need two wombs for this to happen. (This is documented in medical literature, independent of halachah.) 2. What makes you think she would not count from the end time, however you define that, of the latest event? 3. What do you think happens when a woman has twins, one boy and one girl?

Comment: A shmatteh rabbi told me about a case where a woman's ovaries were not taking turns like they were supposed to. Instead, after the birth of a child, they were both cycling at the same time. It became almost impossible to get clean and even then it was only for a few days. Luckily after another child they started working properly again. The only thing this has this to do with your question is that halacha doesn't bother itself with how or why a woman became tamei. If it happened, it happened.

Comment: @user6 you're talking about post-rzeira. Classically it makes a big difference

Comment: @Double I'm not sure what you are referring to...

Comment: @user6591 Well, things like המפלת תוך מלאת פטורה מן הקרבן and would get a new count for Dam Tohar (and a new מלאת for another fetus)

Comment: @Double Ah. True. Which begs the question how would they know? Unless they're hergeishim let them know which side was at work. Truth is I shouldn't have made such a blanketed statement before. Even nowadays women should probably be reckoning chazakos on an every other cycle as well, just in case each side has it's own rhythm.

Comment: @user6 isn't that what a veset leseirugin is?

Comment: @Double That was always presented as a theoretical based on any repeating cycle. This is a real fact. But you're right, if reached right, this would be covered as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like she  starts to count again from the second birth. The Rambam Isurey Biah 10:15 says

הִפִּילָה שִׁלְיָא תְּחִלָּה וְאַחַר כָּךְ יָלְדָה וָלָד שֶׁל קַיָּמָא חוֹשְׁשִׁין לַשִּׁלְיָא שֶׁהִיא וָלָד אַחֵר וְאֵין תּוֹלִין אוֹתָהּ בַּוָּלָד הַבָּא אַחֲרֶיהָ. שֶׁאֵין דַּרְכָּהּ שֶׁל שִׁלְיָא לָצֵאת לִפְנֵי הַוָּלָד. יָצָאת מִקְצָת הַשִּׁלְיָא בַּיּוֹם הָרִאשׁוֹן וּמִקְצָתָהּ בַּשֵּׁנִי מוֹנִין לָהּ מִיּוֹם הָרִאשׁוֹן וְאֵין נוֹתְנִין לָהּ יְמֵי טָהֳרָה אֶלָּא מִיּוֹם שֵׁנִי לְהַחֲמִיר:

*[When a woman] discharges a placenta and afterwards bears a viable child, we suspect that the placenta came as the result of another fetus.We do not associate it with the child that was born afterwards, for it is not usual for the placenta to emerge before the fetus.
If a portion of the placenta emerges on Sunday and a portion emerges on Monday, we count [her days of impurity] from the first day and we count her days of purity only from the second day as a stringency*

The last sentence implies that if we **know** there are two different births we would go by the second one.

Comment: To be clear it's not that we count from the second one but we count from each. If she has a girl on day 1 and a boy on day 30, she still has dam tohar from the girl after day 70.